# Arangodb: Concept of module context

Tags: arangodb, foxx

I do not really understand the concept of "module context" of one service in ArangoDB.
https://docs.arangodb.com/3.11/develop/foxx-microservices/reference/service-context/

Can anyone give a simple example of where this "context" should be used?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 2):

[Foxx Getting started](https://docs.arangodb.com/3.11/develop/foxx-microservices/getting-started/) reveals the following:

> The module.context is the so-called Foxx context or service context.
> This variable is available in all files that are part of your Foxx
> service and provides access to Foxx APIs specific to the current
> service, like the use method, which tells Foxx to mount the router in
> this service (and to expose its routes to HTTP).